# How inject $scope in template compile?

Tags: angularjs

When the user click on a button, I want to load a template in a html file and compile it with the scope and retrieve result to inject it in jsPDF.

For the moment, I succeed to load template and inject the result compiled to jsPDF but dynamic data isn't replaced.

How can I do that?

The function launched when the user click on the button:

```
$scope.getPDF = function () {
    var templateUrl = $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl('views/customerDashboard/invoice.html');

    $templateRequest(templateUrl).then(function(template) {
        $scope.test = 'Hello world!';

        var result = $compile(template)($scope);
        invoice_generator(result[0].innerHTML);
    }, function() {
        // An error has occurred
    });
};
```

The invoice.html file:

```
<div>
    <p>{{ test }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to run it through the $interpolate service since interpolations happen *after* linking (injected like $compile):

```
invoice_generator($interpolate(result[0].innerHTML)(scope));
```

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cwqo58b4/